# E: Unable to locate package mosquitto

Tags: apt, package-management, raspbian, mqtt

I'm trying to install the mosquitto package, but when I type `sudo apt-get install mosquitto` it returns `E: Unable to locate package mosquitto`.

I already ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Output from `apt search mosquitto`:

```
Sortierung... Fertig
Volltextsuche... Fertig
libmosquitto1/now 1.5.7-1+deb10u1 armhf  [Installiert,lokal]
  MQTT version 3.1/3.1.1 client library

mosquitto-clients/now 1.5.7-1+deb10u1 armhf  [Installiert,lokal]
  Mosquitto command line MQTT clients
```

(sorry for the german parts.) It seems like it's already installed? But when I run `mosquitto_sub -d -t /home/data` to test, I only get `Error: Connection refused`

Output from `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
#deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Seems like there's a problem with '`apt-get update`, so I tried fixing it with `debsums`, like in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320988/apt-get-update-with-https-sources-broken) thread, but `apt-get update` can't find the debsums package to install on the first hand...

Comment: The output says that libmosquitto & the mosquitto clients are installed not the broker (they are 3 separate packages). Are there any errors in the `apt-get update` output (do they match the linked question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [apt-file](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file) or as alternative the [online search](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) to search for package names.

You will find that [mosquitto](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/mosquitto) is indeed the correct **Debian package name** to install the server part. The command `mosquitto_sub` is provided by package [mosquitto-clients](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/mosquitto-clients).

However, the `sources.list` provided indicates that your installation is not based on Debian but based on Raspberry Pi OS (previously called Raspbian) in version `buster`. The repository [contains the packages](http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mosquitto/) as well.

Please check carefully your file `sources.list`. It seems that the repository is commented out. Remove the `#` in the first line eventually? The file should look similar as this:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main

# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: Thank you! Editing ```sources.list``` worked. Tho I don't understand how that problem occured on the first hand...